# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, no info

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access

im getting the infamous EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
im compiling in Xcode 6.1 project is written in Swift.

im having a problem understanding the crash, the only info i could get is this:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0xef65e, 0x0000000192ba3bd0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1399ebeb8)
frame #0: 0x0000000192ba3bd0 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 16
frame #1: 0x0000000186c78d70 UIKit`_UIConvertDisplayPointToWindow + 404
frame #2: 0x0000000186f08114 UIKit`__70+[UIWindow _hitTestToPoint:forEvent:windowServerHitTestWindow:screen:]_block_invoke + 136
frame #3: 0x0000000186c51580 UIKit`+[UIWindow _topVisibleWindowPassingTest:] + 176
frame #4: 0x0000000186f08074 UIKit`+[UIWindow _hitTestToPoint:forEvent:windowServerHitTestWindow:screen:] + 148
frame #5: 0x0000000186eea990 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 8812
frame #6: 0x0000000186c4b8f4 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1616
frame #7: 0x00000001824560e8 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
frame #8: 0x000000018245538c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
frame #9: 0x000000018245343c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 712
frame #10: 0x00000001823811f4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
frame #11: 0x000000018b5175a4 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 168
frame #12: 0x0000000186cb2784 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1488
* frame #13: 0x00000001001b2700 #APPNAME#`top_level_code + 76 at AppDelegate.swift:18
frame #14: 0x00000001001b280c #APPNAME#`main + 48 at AppDelegate.swift:0
frame #15: 0x00000001931fea08 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

How do i start debugging this?

Comment: we need more context to help you out... Can you please show us more of your code. 

And try maybe Cleaning your project, that sometimes can help fix any cached linked library that might be giving that compiler error, if it is a compiler error, when exactly do you get this error?

Comment: the error occured when clicking on a button...
it would only occur when going through a few screens in a very specific order... 
somehow cleaning and restarting xcode fixed the error...
you are welcome to add an answer and i will accept...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am glad that cleaning the code helped... it is very uncommon for this type of thing to happen but happen often enough that you will remember to clean code once in a while.

---

My original Comment.
Try maybe Cleaning your project, that sometimes can help fix any cached linked library that might be giving that compiler error, if it is a compiler error, when exactly do you get this error?

And might want to add this for any future problems, when an Exec Bad access error happens it's usually that you are accessing an object that is nil or became nil at some point in time and trying to use it, so keep in check those strong and weak references.